# How to loop through an array declared in the header file?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have declared my header file with a structure consisting of arrays. It looks like this:

```
 #ifndef HEADER_H_
 #define HEADER_H_

  typedef struct{
     uint32_t State[3];
     }h_t;

 #endif
```

The C file that accesses this header file looks as follows:

```
  #include"Header.h"
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  char* old_states[3];


  old_states[0] ="ABC";
  old_states[1] ="BAC";
  old_states[2] ="AAC";

  h_t var;
  for(i=0; i<3;i++){
    var.State[i] = old_states[i];
    printf("\n The state is %s", var.State[i]);
     }
```

I print the states out to check them. THey are:

```
The state is ABC
The state is BAC
The state is AAC
```

Now I want to loop through each `var.State[n]`, like `var.State[0]`, `var.State[1]`, `var.State[2]` individually.

That is loop through `var.State[0] ="ABC"` so that I could access each of the letters(`A`,`B`,`C`) individually. Can somebody tell me how could I achieve this?

Comment: `for(int i = 0;i < strlen(old_states[0]);i++)
{
     char ch = old_states[0][i];
}`

Comment: wait, what? `var.State[i] = old_states[i];`....

Comment: *The C file that accesses this header file looks as follows* -- No it doesn't, because there's no way this compiles.

Comment: Enable warnings, **read** them and **act accordingly**! And post a [mcve]

Comment: @Olaf: I missed the fact that I had declared a uint32 type in there. Rectified the mistake.

Comment: __After getting an answer, please do not change the question in a way  that makes the existing answer appear invalid.__ Thank you.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Sry for that. The question is back to the original one..

Comment: Thanks. I rolled back your edit. However, you're always welcome to [edit] your question and add relevant details **without** changing the actual question. You can append your improved version always. Hope I'm clear. :-)

Comment: @Goldengirl  Please take a look at the edited answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you declared  `uint32_t State[3];` and printing it with `%s` specifier that creates problem.

You can declare `State[3];` as a 2-D character array like this -

### EDIT

```
char State[3][4];
```

And to store values -

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
    memcpy(var.State[i],old_states[i],strlen(old_states[i]);
 }
```

And access each character like this -

```
var.State[i][j]
```

To print each character

```
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
         {
            printf("%c",var.State[i][j]);
         }
       printf("\n");
     }
```

Comment: You are missing the trailing NUL for strings. That will exhibit _undefined behaviour_. Also `State` is **not** the actual problem. And: assigning a pointer to an array?

Comment: While it works, it is obviously not OPs intention to copy the strings, but to assing the pointers. This is not only the faster way, but also the more portable (e.g. change the strings). Sorry, but I think your approach is wrong.

Comment: @Olaf No worries !! and thanks for correcting me  :)

Answer (score 4):

In your code, `old_states[n]`is of `char *`, a pointer. OTOH, `var.State[i]` is of type `uint32_t` and they are not same.

A pointer type *maybe* converted to an integer type, but the result is strictly implementation dependent. To take this further, as stated in `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3,

> If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

So, basically you should avoid doing this unless you *really really* know what you're doing.

Then, in case of

```
 printf("\n The state is %s", var.State[i])
```

`%s` expects a `char *` (*a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type*, to be exact, and in case the precision is not specified, it should be null-terminated), but what you're passing is `uint32_t`. It is called  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) again, as per the above point.

*Moral of the story: **enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them***.

---

Solution:

Preferable, change your structure member type from

```
 uint32_t State[3];
```

to

```
char * State[3];
```

then, assign them as you're doing now and finally, for accessing all *individual* elements, you can do something like (*pseudocode*)

```
 for(i=0; i<3;i++)
 {
      int len = strlen(var.State[i]);

      for(j=0; j < len ;j++) printf("%c \t", var.State[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I completley ignored the fact that I had declared the var.State is of type uint32_t.